# Index out of range GraphCat.Parent OpenBUGS

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a FHMM in R and OpenBUGS, but am now stuck on the following error.

At first OpenBUGS simply gave me the annoying "Something went wrong" error, after renaming Traphandler.ocf to Traphandler_simple.ocf, I was able to see that an "index out of range" error occured in GraphCat.Parents. Even though, I was unable to locate the offending piece of code (know nothing about Fortran and little about MCMC)

The structure of the FHMM I was trying to construct has M=3 sub chains (s[m,n] where m=1,2,3 and n=1,...,100 in my code), each sub chain has K=2 states, and the emissions y is a linear Gaussian of the 3 chains' emissions

Here is my model,

```
# M=3, K=2, N=100

model <- function() {
  for( m in 1:M ) {
    s[m,1] ~ dcat(pi[m,1:K])    # initial states of each sub-chain
  }
  for( m in 1:M ) {
    for( i in 2:N ) {
      s[m,i] ~ dcat(trans[s[m,i-1],1:K,m])    # dim(trans) is c(2,2,3)
    }
  }
  for( m in 1:M ) {
    for( i in 1:N ) {
      mu0[m,i] <- mu[m,s[m,i]]
      sigma[m,i] <- 1/tau[m,s[m,i]]
    }
  }

  for( i in 1:N ) {
    mm[i] <- sum(mu0[1:M,i])
    tt[i] <- 1/sum(sigma[1:M,i])
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mm[i],tt[i])
  }
}
```

And this is how I set initial values and data in R,

```
# Initial values
s.B <- matrix(rep(M*N),nrow=M,ncol=N)
for(i in 1:M) {
  s.B[i,] <- sample(1:K, N, replace=TRUE, rdirichlet(1,rep(1, K)))
}
inits <- function() {list(s=s.B)}

# data
P1 <- array(dim=c(2,2,3))
for( i in 1:M ) {
  P1[,,i] <- rdirichlet(K,rep(1, K))
}
K <- 2,
M <- 3,
N <- 100,
pi <- rdirichlet(M,rep(1, K)),
trans <- P1,
mu <- mus + rnorm(M*K,0,1),
sigma <- sigmas + rnorm(M*K,0,0.3)
tau <- 1/sigma

# y is the observed sequence of data
data <- list("y","pi","trans","mu","tau","N","K","M")

# Parameters
params <- c("s")
```

It seems the error occurred when OpenBUGS was trying to sample s[1,2],
but I have not a slightly related clue of what that means.
(stackoverflow does not allow me to post screen capture until I have 10 reputations ...)